# How to catch a form when it's submitted and forward form values to Dotmailer?

Tags: drupal-8

I've been asked to make a change to a Drupal 8 site (I'm not a Drupal Developer), the client would like an enquiry form linking up with Dotmailer. Within the theme I've tried to create a handler based on some information that I found online. But I don't know if it's doing anything. I've checked the logs section of Drupal and there isn't anything logged to indicate that the custom handler was actioned.

My theme is named abc-primary, and inside the theme folder I have created the file abc_primary.theme with the following contents;

```
<?php

use Drupal\media\Entity\Media;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_form_system_theme_settings_alter().
 */
function abc_primary_form_system_theme_settings_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $theme_file = drupal_get_path('theme', 'abc_primary') . '/abc_primary.theme';
    $build_info = $form_state->getBuildInfo();
    if (!in_array($theme_file, $build_info['files'])) {
        $build_info['files'][] = $theme_file;
    }
    $form_state->setBuildInfo($build_info);

    $form['#submit'][] = 'abc_primary_form_system_theme_settings_submit';
}

function abc_primary_form_system_theme_settings_submit(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // TODO: Extra submission logic.
    // This submit handler will be called before default submit handler for this form.
    \Drupal::logger('mymodule')->notice('mymodule submit ') ;
}
```

Is the above correct or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new module, and define following method:

```
function mymodule_form_node_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    //you may want to check your form_id by
    // $form['#form_id'] 
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][]  = 'mymodule_node_form_submit';
}

function mymodule_node_form_submit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
   // get values from form_state
   //log or send to desired web service
}
```

Hope it helps.